# Map on JSP to human readable HTML

Tags: java, javascript, json, jsp

So on my JSP I have my command/model object that has a Map(String, Object) variable. The map values are either Strings or more Map(String, Object), which in turn contain the same thing, and so on down a few layers. The contents is totally dynamic so I can't create set Pojos from the map data.

If I just try and output ${command.map} I get a huge amount of data that looks similar to JSON but isn't quite;

```
 {Degree 1={Student Name on Record={First Name=John, Middle Name=D, Last Name=Smithereens, Name Suffix=Jr},
```

I want to output something similar to json.human.js : http://marianoguerra.github.io/json.human.js/

However that doesn't seem to accept my input, as its not quite JSON?

Any idea how I can use the JSP map to produce human readable html or convert the output JSP map into JSON for input in json.human.js?

Comment: Have you tried writing your own formatter which after `{` would add line separator `<br />` and increase indentation level? Also before writing new line add tabulation or some fixed-number-of-whitespaces*indentation-level. Also add `<br/>` after each `}` and decrease indentation level.

Comment: Here http://ideone.com/SmTC96 is example of what I meant in my previous comment in pure Java. Hope you will be able to implement your own solution based on it.